# Sitting alone . .

Tags: conditional-constructions, phrases

> Sitting alone, you may find quiet.

May you call this first, maybe, phrase(?), a conditional?

Comment: Where did you get this sentence?

Comment: It is normally called a *participle phrase*. *Walking down the street, you may step in some chewing gum.*   Are you asking if such phrases share some similarities with conditionals?

Answer (score 0):

> Sitting alone, you may find quiet.

The part - *sitting alone* - is not a phrase; modern grammarians classify it as a clause - a Gerund-Participle Clause, that is. The function of it in the sentence is an Adjunct.

The structure of this Gerund-Participle clause is like this - *VERB-ing + Predicative complement*. The subject of the clause is not explicitly mentioned, but it is understood. The subject of this Gerund-Participle clause is nothing other than the subject of the sentence - *you*.

The meaning, however, is ambiguous. It can mean the following -

- While sitting alone, you may find quiet.
- Because you are sitting alone, you may find quiet.

The context will help you further with the meaning. But normally there is no conditional meaning to it. (I am not clear what you are asking when you mentioned "conditional")

---

Traditional grammarian will call *sitting alone* as Adverbial (what modern grammarians call Adjunct).

Comment: In traditional grammar, "sitting" functions here as a present participle, modifying "you". An adverbial phrase or clause would modify "find".